# Ошибка при запуске сервера

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, wildfly

17:29:10,933 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 13837ms - Started 401 of 615 services (23 services failed or missing dependencies, 314 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Здравствуйте. В чем ошибка при запуске сервера?

standole.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:6.0">
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.core-management"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.elytron"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
</extensions>
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <audit-log>
        <formatters>
            <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
        </formatters>
        <handlers>
            <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </handlers>
        <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="file"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
    </audit-log>
    <management-interfaces>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
    <access-control provider="simple">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local"/>
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
</management>
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:4.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:2.0">
        <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
        <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
        <job-repository name="in-memory">
            <in-memory/>
        </job-repository>
        <thread-pool name="batch">
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:core-management:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <concurrent>
            <context-services>
                <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
            </context-services>
            <managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
            </managed-thread-factories>
            <managed-executor-services>
                <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
            </managed-executor-services>
            <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
            </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
        </concurrent>
        <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
        <caches>
            <cache name="simple"/>
            <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
        </caches>
        <passivation-stores>
            <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
        </passivation-stores>
        <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
            <data-stores>
                <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </data-stores>
        </timer-service>
        <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default">
            <channel-creation-options>
                <option name="READ_TIMEOUT" value="${prop.remoting-connector.read.timeout:20}" type="xnio"/>
                <option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="1234" type="remoting"/>
            </channel-creation-options>
        </remote>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
        <default-security-domain value="other"/>
        <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:2.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
        <providers>
            <aggregate-providers name="combined-providers">
                <providers name="elytron"/>
                <providers name="openssl"/>
            </aggregate-providers>
            <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
            <provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/>
        </providers>
        <audit-logging>
            <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
        </audit-logging>
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                <realm name="local"/>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
        <security-realms>
            <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
            <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </properties-realm>
            <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </properties-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <mappers>
            <simple-permission-mapper name="default-permission-mapper" mapping-mode="first">
                <permission-mapping>
                    <principal name="anonymous"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                </permission-mapping>
                <permission-mapping match-all="true">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                </permission-mapping>
            </simple-permission-mapper>
            <constant-realm-mapper name="local" realm-name="local"/>
            <simple-role-decoder name="groups-to-roles" attribute="groups"/>
            <constant-role-mapper name="super-user-mapper">
                <role name="SuperUser"/>
            </constant-role-mapper>
        </mappers>
        <http>
            <http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" security-domain="ManagementDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                <mechanism-configuration>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST">
                        <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    </mechanism>
                </mechanism-configuration>
            </http-authentication-factory>
            <http-authentication-factory name="application-http-authentication" security-domain="ApplicationDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                <mechanism-configuration>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="BASIC">
                        <mechanism-realm realm-name="Application Realm"/>
                    </mechanism>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="FORM"/>
                </mechanism-configuration>
            </http-authentication-factory>
            <provider-http-server-mechanism-factory name="global"/>
        </http>
        <sasl>
            <sasl-authentication-factory name="management-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ManagementDomain">
                <mechanism-configuration>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                        <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    </mechanism>
                </mechanism-configuration>
            </sasl-authentication-factory>
            <sasl-authentication-factory name="application-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
                <mechanism-configuration>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                    <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                        <mechanism-realm realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    </mechanism>
                </mechanism-configuration>
            </sasl-authentication-factory>
            <configurable-sasl-server-factory name="configured" sasl-server-factory="elytron">
                <properties>
                    <property name="wildfly.sasl.local-user.default-user" value="$local"/>
                </properties>
            </configurable-sasl-server-factory>
            <mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory name="elytron" sasl-server-factory="global">
                <filters>
                    <filter provider-name="WildFlyElytron"/>
                </filters>
            </mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory>
            <provider-sasl-server-factory name="global"/>
        </sasl>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:2.0">
        <worker name="default"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:5.0">
        <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
            <local-cache name="default">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <object-memory size="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <object-memory size="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0">
        <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
        <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
        <default-workmanager>
            <short-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </short-running-threads>
            <long-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </long-running-threads>
        </default-workmanager>
        <cached-connection-manager/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
        <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:3.0">
        <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
        <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
        <deployment-permissions>
            <maximum-set>
                <permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
            </maximum-set>
        </deployment-permissions>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
                <authentication-jaspi>
                    <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                        <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                    </login-module-stack>
                    <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
                </authentication-jaspi>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:4.0">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
        <object-store path="tx-object-store" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:5.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/11"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:4.0"/>
</profile>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: Никто не скажет, она произошла намного раньше по логу и может быть в чём угодно

Comment: @RomanDanilov, и ччто делать?

Comment: можете показать свой standalone.xml файл? возможно вы что то там добавили/изменили и там кавычка или ещё что нибудь не дописали или ещё что то...

Comment: А у вас что-то не работает? По записи вижу, что 401 сервис запущен и работает, соответственно в целом сервер стартанул.

Comment: Да, не работает выводит сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Да, не работает выводит сообщение об ошибке